# Reference Request - The Theorema Egregium

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Where can I find a good proof of the Theorema Egregium that downplays the modern language of differential geometry?

Comment: Not sure if the proof is there, but you might want to check [Kuhnel's book](https://www.amazon.fr/Differential-Geometry-Curves-Surfaces-Manifolds/dp/0821839888)

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking at Michael Spivak's text, *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. II*.  I believe that one chapter includes Gauss's original work along with a running translation and description in more modern language on the facing page as well as a section about how to read Gauss.